# There is an error shown in grocery store project. Can you help me solve it?

Tags: node.js, ejs

[it is error shown when i go to main url i.e, '/'. except this everything is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkN8W.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is stated in the error. Admittedly it's a little hard to spot, but it is: "products is not defined at eval (E:\IT\SEM-7\Project\a\project\views\products\index.ejs)". Without seeing your code, it's impossible to pinpoint why exactly this is happening.

Comment: @JaydeepParmar I'm not going to debug your code for you; make sure `products` is defined somewhere, try debugging it yourself.